# Get form value in Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I am new to servlet. What I'm trying to do is upload the file to my server using servlet alongside I send one text value which is file name to change in server side. The problem is I submit the form data to servlet using ajax post but in my servlet, I'm getting null value from request.getParameter.

This is my html;

```
$("#fileUp").html(  "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id='uploadForm' action='" + url + "/PrjHRService/FileUpload'>"+
                        "<input name='file' id='file' type='file' size='50'>"+
                        "<input name='fname' type='text' >"+
                        "<input id='btnUpload' value='Upload' type='submit'>"+
                        //"<div id='imgLink'></div>"+
                        "</form>" );
```

This is my jquery ajax call to server;

```
$("#uploadForm").submit(function() {            
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: $("#uploadForm").attr("action"),
                   data: formData, 
                   async: false,
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       if(data.res === "true"){
                         jsi.showMsg("Uploaded Successfully");
                         $("#imgLink").html("Uploaded Successfully");
                       }else{
                         jsi.showMsg("Error Uploading");    
                       }
                   },
                   contentType: false,
                   processData: false
                 });

            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });
```

This is how I get the value from form in my servlet; In there you will see the line String fileExt=request.getParameter("fname"); I found out that fileExt is null which is my problem.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
      // Check that we have a file upload request
      isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
      response.setContentType("application/json");
      String fileExt=request.getParameter("fname");
      java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
      if( !isMultipart ){

         JSONObject o=new JSONObject();
          try {
            o.put("res", "false");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          out.println(o.toString());

         return;
      }
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try{ 
      // Parse the request to get file items.
      List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

      // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
      while ( i.hasNext () ) 
      {
         FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
         if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
         {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            //String[] parts = fileName.split(".");
            //fileName = parts[0] + "." + parts[1];
            String contentType = fi.getContentType();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            fi.write( file ) ;
            JSONObject o=new JSONObject();
            o.put("res", "true");
            //out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
            out.println(o.toString());
            //out.println("Uploaded Successfully");
         }
      }
     /* out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");*/
   }catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upload file, `<form/>`'s `method` must be set to `POST`. Then, at the server side, you need to get input stream from the request and read data --- and you need to do that in `doPost` method (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29). Of course there are many libraries, that do that from you, e.g. those from apache.

You must remember, that using `POST` with `enctype="multipart/from-data"` adds **all** form's parameters to POST body, what is distinctive from `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` where parameters are concatenated to request URL (as so called QUERY_STRING). Method `getParameter` works only on parameters sent via URL. So in your case you need to read POST data, parse it and find out the value of `fname`. POST that might look like this:

```
-----------------------------8022333619518
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fname"

myfilename.txt
-----------------------------8022333619518
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Send
-----------------------------8022333619518--
```

If you add manually some parameters to `action` URL, `getParameter` method will find it.

And as you do not upload any file (aren't you?) you can set `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to use `getParameter`, as it adds all form's inputs to URL. But your code suggests, that you will upload a file later, so it won't work for the file content.

As you use `ServletFileUpload` from Apache, you can see [parseParameterMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html#parseParameterMap%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) method, get the map, then get `fname` parameter (it should be first element on the list) as `FileItem` and get its content with `getString`. It should be what you are looking for:

```
Map<String, List<FileItem>> map = ServletFileUpload.parseParameterMap(request);
List<FileItem> list = map.get("fname");
if (list != null && list.size() >= 1) {
    FileItem item = list.get(0);
    System.out.println("And the winner is... " + item.getString);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Dammit! Still no luck!");
}
```

Comment: Both are with POST. I can upload file but I can't get value of text input which is "fname".

Comment: Can you provide your `doPost` method of your servlet that handles it? Also please check link to the documentation I've just placed in the answer.

Comment: I just added doPost method. Thanks.

Comment: yeah I'm uploading file at the same time I'm submitting text input alongside. So..